# Divide the posts by it's children categories

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, taxonomy

In a custom post type's taxonomy page, I want to divide the posts by it's children categories like below:

**H2:Child Category1**

Article list

**H2:Child Category2**

Article list

**H2:Child Category3**

Article list

I could do it using queries with the categories manually, but as categories might be added later, it will be suitable if we could work around with a more flexible(cms like) solution. 
Here is my code, that prints a normal list with all the posts not divided by categories. What should I do?

```
<ul class="menenlis">
        <?php
            if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post();
            $locations = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'menucat');
            $location = $locations[0]->name;
            $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'gallery-thumb');
            if(empty($thumbnail)) $thumbnail = APP_URL . "images/common/no-image.jpg";
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="">
                <div class="imager" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>);"></div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h3 class="name"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <p class="read">/read/</p>
                    <p class="price">/price/</p>
                    <p class="caption-b">/caption-b/</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; endif;?>
</ul>
```

Comment: _“What should I do?”_ - implement a basic [control break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break) … Records needs to be ordered by child category, and inside your loop you simply check if the child category of the current item is still the same as for the previous one … if it is not, you output the headline element with the child category name first.

Comment: Sorry but I cant picture how to even start doing so...